# XSLT 2: Add an element with an incremented value to a list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT and have spent hours trying to figure out a solution to a problem that seems to look kind of trivial.

I have a xml document which contains a list like that:

```
  <Header>
    <URLList>
      <URLItem type="type1">
        <URL></URL>
      </URLItem>
      <URLItem type="type2">
        <URL>2</URL>
      </URLItem>
    </URLList>
  </Header>
```

If it doesn't exist, I now need to add an "ID" Element to each URLItem. The value of the ID Element has to be an incremented value.

The xml should look like this in the end:

```
  <Header>
    <URLList>
      <URLItem type="type1">
        <ID>1</ID>
        <URL></URL>
      </URLItem>
      <URLItem type="type2">
        <ID>2</ID>
        <URL>2</URL>
      </URLItem>
    </URLList>
  </Header>
```

I have been trying various things, but could not get it working correctly.

For instance, if I try to use a template to match the List, I am not able to get the correct incremented value. The ID value is [2,4], but not [1,2] as it should... This is the xslt:

```
  <xsl:template match="/Header/URLList/URLItem[not(child::ID)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ID> <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></ID>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have been also trying to use a for-each loop like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="/Header/URLList">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Header/URLList/URLItem">
        <xsl:if test="not(ID)">
          <xsl:element name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

This way I seem to get the increment right, but the new ID Elements appear at the parent node. I haven't been able to find a way to attach them as a child of the URLItem element.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reason you get 2,4,6 rather than 1,2,3 is that the xsl:apply-templates element (which you haven't shown us) selects the whitespace text nodes as well as the elements. You can avoid this by only selecting the elements (select="*"), or by stripping whitespace text nodes before you start using xsl:strip-space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
  <xsl:template match="/Header/URLList/URLItem[not(child::ID)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <ID> <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></ID>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

use

```
  <xsl:template match="/Header/URLList/URLItem[not(child::ID)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <ID><xsl:number/></ID>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Header>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//URLList"/>
</Header>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="URLList">
<URLList>
<xsl:for-each select="URLItem[not(child::ID)]">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <ID> <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></ID>
      <xsl:copy-of select="URL"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </URLList>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```